# Struggling with the formatting of scraped College football results

Tags: python, pandas, beautifulsoup

Python newbie here. I am trying to format imported college football scores (from Massey Ratings)so I can import them into Excel. I need to create some headers["Date", "Winner", "Score", "Loser", "Score"] and add some space between the columns for readability.From what I can gather Pandas DataFrame is the way to go. Any help would be much appreciated.

Here is my code so far:

```
import pandas as pd
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib.request

address = 'https://www.masseyratings.com/scores.php?s=308075&sub=11604&dt=20191119'
response = urllib.request.urlopen(address)
html = response.read()

soup = BeautifulSoup(html,"html.parser")


table = soup.find("pre").get_text(strip=True)



print(table)
```

The Output I am getting:

```
2019-11-16Southern Miss36 @UT San Antonio17           
2019-11-16 @Washington St49Stanford22           
2019-11-16TCU33 @Texas Tech31           
2019-11-16 @Temple29Tulane21           
2019-11-16Troy63 @Texas St27           
2019-11-16 @UAB37UTEP10           
2019-11-16 @Utah49UCLA3           
2019-11-16 @Utah St26Wyoming21           
2019-11-16 @Clemson52Wake Forest3           
2019-11-16 @Florida St49Alabama St12           
2019-11-16Virginia Tech45 @Georgia Tech0           
2019-11-16Ohio St56 @Rutgers21           
2019-11-16 @Iowa St23Texas21           
2019-11-16 @BYU42Idaho St10           
2019-11-19Ohio0 @Bowling Green0 Sch       
2019-11-19E Michigan0 @N Illinois0 Sch
```

Comment: Okay, cool. So you've got some code and some results. _Specifically_, what's wrong with the results? What do you expect them to look like? Please read [ask].

Comment: Thanks Chris. I would like the data to be formatted in a table format with spaces between the columns - similar to a Excel worksheet

Comment: What do you mean by "table"? How does that map to "so I can import them into Excel"? How do you expect each line to be split into columns?

Comment: Is it possible to insert a couple spaces after the date, the winning team, the winning score, the losing team and the losing score? This should improve readability.

Comment: Yes, it's possible to do that. I'd start by peeling the date off the front of each string since it has a consistent length and format, then dealing with the second half separately. But adding spaces to your ou8tput won't get you any closer to importing into Excel. What's your _actual_ end goal? Please read about the [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/248627).

Answer (score 0):

String splitting might be a good idea but you can use regex patterns for this particular page to extract the 4 columns

```
import re, csv, requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs

r = requests.get('https://www.masseyratings.com/scores.php?s=308075&sub=11604&dt=20191119')
soup = bs(r.content, 'lxml')
p = re.compile(r'([^0-9-]+)\s{3,}')
p2 = re.compile(r'\s(\d+)\s')

with open("data.csv", "w", encoding="utf-8-sig", newline='') as csv_file:
    w = csv.writer(csv_file, delimiter = ",", quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL)
    w.writerow(['Date','Winner','Score1','Loser','Score2'])

    for line in soup.select_one('pre').text.split('\n')[:-4]:
        matches1 = p.findall(line)
        matches2 = p2.findall(line)
        row = [re.search(r'(\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2})',line).group(0), matches1[0].strip(), matches2[0], matches1[1].strip(), matches2[1]]
        w.writerow(row)
```